# Apple Crash log not able to replicate issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash

We have been trying to submit an app with Apple for the last month and it keeps coming back rejected for small reasons. We are completely stuck with this last response and have no idea how to proceed.

They said the app crashed when creating a profile on our app. The problem is we thoroughly tested this on 4 different devices (iPhone 5, iPhone5S, iPhone 6S, iPad Air) and it works flawlessly for us.

They provided us a crash log but after hours of reading it and Googling we are coming up dry. Any help understanding what this crash log means will be a greatly appreciated.

```
Incident Identifier: 1985D6ED-9ED1-428D-9E27-41DBFD053205
CrashReporter Key:   7623e816ce9df811618c4e9b022a6c8f3c98bddb
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             fitDEGREE [784]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/706E0CE8-B30F-4F30-B1B4-BEFE5F3FC51A/fitDEGREE.app/fitDEGREE
Identifier:          com.FitDegree.fitDEGREE
Version:             3 (1.0.1)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-02-02 12:11:39.39 -0800
Launch Time:         2016-02-02 12:07:56.56 -0800
OS Version:          iOS 9.2.1 (13D15)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1832cd900 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x18293bf80 objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1831bc1a8 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 324
3   CoreFoundation                  0x1831bc040 +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 64
4   fitDEGREE                       0x1000b7964 0x10006c000 + 309604
5   fitDEGREE                       0x10014f4b4 0x10006c000 + 930996
6   fitDEGREE                       0x100127a94 0x10006c000 + 768660
7   fitDEGREE                       0x10014efec 0x10006c000 + 929772
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x182d21630 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x182d215f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x182d26cf8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1844
11  CoreFoundation                  0x183284bb0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
12  CoreFoundation                  0x183282a18 __CFRunLoopRun + 1628
13  CoreFoundation                  0x1831b1680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
14  GraphicsServices                0x1846c0088 GSEventRunModal + 180
15  UIKit                           0x188028d90 UIApplicationMain + 204
16  fitDEGREE                       0x1000fe758 0x10006c000 + 599896
17  libdyld.dylib                   0x182d528b8 start + 4


Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
0.099409     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183948708 TCP Conn 0x158cf1640 started
0.293100     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183947104 TCP Conn 0x158b19340 complete. fd: 22, err: 0
0.293568     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183948630 TCP Conn 0x158b19340 event 1. err: 0
0.377927     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183948708 TCP Conn 0x158b19340 started



Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182e70140 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182f38ef8 pthread_kill + 112
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000182de1dac abort + 140
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001829153f4 __cxa_bad_cast + 0
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000182931e98 default_unexpected_handler() + 0
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018293c248 _objc_terminate() + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018292ef44 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018292e85c __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*) + 0
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018293c094 _objc_exception_destructor(void*) + 0
9   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001831bc1a8 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 324
10  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001831bc040 +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 64
11  fitDEGREE                       0x00000001000b7964 0x10006c000 + 309604
12  fitDEGREE                       0x000000010014f4b4 0x10006c000 + 930996
13  fitDEGREE                       0x0000000100127a94 0x10006c000 + 768660
14  fitDEGREE                       0x000000010014efec 0x10006c000 + 929772
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182d21630 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182d215f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182d26cf8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1844
18  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183284bb0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
19  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183282a18 __CFRunLoopRun + 1628
20  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001831b1680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
21  GraphicsServices                0x00000001846c0088 GSEventRunModal + 180
22  UIKit                           0x0000000188028d90 UIApplicationMain + 204
23  fitDEGREE                       0x00000001000fe758 0x10006c000 + 599896
24  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000182d528b8 start + 4

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182e714fc kevent_qos + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182d3494c _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 232
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182d237bc _dispatch_source_invoke + 0

Thread 2 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182e554bc mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182e55338 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183284ac0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001832827c4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001831b1680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000183921434 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 412
6   Foundation                      0x0000000183c8fc40 __NSThread__start__ + 1000
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182f37b28 _pthread_body + 156
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182f37a8c _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182f35028 thread_start + 4

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182e70368 __select + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018328b028 __CFSocketManager + 648
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182f37b28 _pthread_body + 156
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182f37a8c _pthread_body + 0
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182f35028 thread_start + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182e70b6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182f35530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182f35020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182e70b6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182f35530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182f35020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 6 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.CoreLocation.ConnectionClient.0x156e82f30.events
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182e55510 semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182d32508 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 160
2   CoreLocation                    0x0000000189b3ed78 0x189b3c000 + 11640
3   CoreLocation                    0x0000000189b437ec 0x189b3c000 + 30700
4   CoreLocation                    0x0000000189b7df28 0x189b3c000 + 270120
5   CoreLocation                    0x0000000189b7bb7c 0x189b3c000 + 260988
6   CoreLocation                    0x0000000189b7bab0 0x189b3c000 + 260784
7   CoreLocation                    0x0000000189b7ccfc 0x189b3c000 + 265468
8   libxpc.dylib                    0x0000000182f69358 _xpc_connection_call_event_handler + 68
9   libxpc.dylib                    0x0000000182f67100 _xpc_connection_mach_event + 2132
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182d216ec _dispatch_client_callout4 + 16
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182d259d8 _dispatch_mach_msg_invoke + 656
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182d2d808 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1332
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182d24aec _dispatch_mach_invoke + 600
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182d2d808 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1332
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182d250f4 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182d2d808 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1332
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182d250f4 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182d215f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182d2fa88 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 2140
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182d2f224 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182f35470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182f35020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182e70b6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182f35530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182f35020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182e70b6c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182f35530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182f35020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 9 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.networking.connection.0x158cf1640
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182e56830 close + 8
1   libsystem_network.dylib         0x0000000182eca31c nw_network_agent_internal_copy_dictionary_for_uuid + 472
2   libsystem_network.dylib         0x0000000182ef089c nw_path_create_evaluator_for_helper_client_id + 2576
3   libsystem_network.dylib         0x0000000182ec298c __tcp_connection_start_block_invoke + 368
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182d21630 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182d215f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182d2d634 _dispatch_queue_drain + 864
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182d250f4 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182d2f504 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 728
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182d2f224 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182f35470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182f35020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 10:

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000158ce0df7
    x4: 0x0000000182932e02   x5: 0x000000016fd91450   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000fa0
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000000000002  x11: 0x0000000000000010
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000002  x14: 0x0000000009010810  x15: 0x0000000010808020
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001a0bbf000  x21: 0x000000016fd91450  x22: 0x0000000156d207d0  x23: 0x800029e5f0542d01
   x24: 0x00000000000000b8  x25: 0x0000000158cf3d00  x26: 0xa006769666e6f636  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0xa0030303a35302d6  fp: 0x000000016fd913b0   lr: 0x0000000182f38ef8
    sp: 0x000000016fd91390   pc: 0x0000000182e70140 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

Comment: There must be some text associated with that `objc_exception_throw`.  Also that crash log hasn't been symbolicated.

Comment: It's failing creating a dictionary. Are you doing anything tricky with it? Show us code where that call is being made.

Comment: @trojanfoe this is my first time trying to symbolicate a crash log. I changed the extension to .crash and put it into xcode. It changed a lot of the memory fields into text. Did I do this incorrectly and if so how do I do it correctly?

Comment: did you try running your app on release mode?